# Why this approach is not working in visualizing quicksort with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, sorting, visualizer

I am making a sorting visualizer in react. With position absolute, I am swapping the transform of the bars. This approach is working fine with BubbleSort but is giving unwanted results in QuickSort. Below is the detailed explanation of the problem.

```
const PIVOT_COLOR = '#FF4949';
const SORTED_COLOR = '#CB6BF9';

async function pivot(blocks, start = 0, end = blocks.length + 1) {
    let pivot = Number(blocks[start].childNodes[0].innerHTML);
    let swapIdx = start;
    let value;

    blocks[start].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = PIVOT_COLOR;

    for (let i = start + 1; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        value = Number(blocks[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML);

        blocks[i].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

        await new Promise((resolve) =>
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
            }, 500)
        );

        if (pivot > value) {
            swapIdx++;

            let arr = [];
            blocks.forEach(el => arr.push(el.childNodes[0].innerHTML));
            console.log(arr);

            //swap(arr, swapIdx, i);
            await swap(blocks[swapIdx], blocks[i]);
        }

        blocks[i].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = SORTED_COLOR;
    }

    await swap(blocks[start], blocks[swapIdx]);
    console.log(swapIdx)
    blocks[start].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = SORTED_COLOR;
    return swapIdx;
}

export async function QuickSort(blocks, left = 0, right = blocks.length - 1) {
    if (left < right) {
        let pivotIndex = await pivot(blocks, left, right);
        //left
        await QuickSort(blocks, left, pivotIndex - 1);
        //right
        await QuickSort(blocks, pivotIndex + 1, right);
    }
}

function swap(el1, el2) {
    let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
    let container = wrapper.childNodes[0];
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var temp = el1.style.transform;
        el1.style.transform = el2.style.transform;
        el2.style.transform = temp;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {

            // For waiting for .25 sec
            setTimeout(() => {
                container.insertBefore(el2, el1);
                resolve();
            }, 250);
        });
    });
}
```

[var naming reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPFLo.png)

When I swap swapIdx and i `swap(blocks[swapIdx], blocks[i])` bars are not swapping in the correct swapIdx as shown in the image below but they are being inserted at the correct position in the DOM.

[Image showing bars not swapping in the correct position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEx3A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- Your code is not really swapping the DOM nodes with a call to `insertBefore`... Instead it *rotates* the elements that are in the range between the two given elements: element 2 is inserted before element 1, and that means that all elements that occured between element 1 and 2 are shifted.
- Your `blocks` array is left unchanged. Nothing is swapped there. Yet you should also swap the nodes in the `blocks` array, as that is the basis for your algorithm to perform comparisons.

To really swap two DOM elements, proceed as follows:

- create temporary dummy element
- call `replaceWith` to swap that element into the document and at the same time take the first element out.
- call `replaceWith` to swap that element (which was taken out) with the other element
- call `replaceWith` to swap the second element with the temporary element.

Comment: As you said blocks array itself is not updating. Also I am using insertBefore which is not doing what I intended to do. So i think i should make another array which contains the current values of my bars, and use that array for sorting.

Comment: That is a good idea. But still, you will still need to swap DOM nodes. So actually swap them instead of moving one before the other.

Comment: Added a paragraph about that to my answer. Have a go at it. If you cannot make it work, ask a new question specifically about swapping DOM nodes, and provide a simple piece of code (not the complete quick sort implementation) to do it with, explaining where you are stuck with it.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as I am asking about how to swap nodes which is a separate topic for another question. Thanks anyway for adding the swapping part too.